# How can I insert commas between pairs of floating point numbers?

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq, delimiter

## What I'm trying to do

I want to draw bounding boxes indicating objects recognized in a locally taken photo from a JSON object downloaded from the REST Google Vision API. I want to draw the bounding boxes using an ImageMagick call as below.

```
convert output.jpg -draw 'stroke red fill none polygon 0,78.7 87,78 87,151 0,151' outputbox.png
```

## How I'm trying to do it

I'm using terminal on Mac OS 10.15.4 (bash, not zsh, I switched it back to bash from zsh.)

I get the JSON response from google just fine as below.

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "localizedObjectAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/0jbk",
          "name": "Animal",
          "score": 0.776703,
          "boundingPoly": {
            "normalizedVertices": [
              {
                "y": 0.327939
              },
              {
                "x": 0.27193785,
                "y": 0.327939
              },
              {
                "x": 0.27193785,
                "y": 0.62985307
              },
              {
                "y": 0.62985307
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

I used jq (as below) to parse the response, and I think I'm probably not using the optimal query to achieve what I want.

INPUT

```
jq '.responses[0][][0].boundingPoly.normalizedVertices[] | if .x==null then 0 else .x*320 end, .y*240' img.json
```

OUTPUT

```
0 78.70536 87.020112 78.70536 87.020112 151.16473680000001 0 151.16473680000001
```

In order to input them into image magick convert as draw coordinates,  I want to output a string where every two numbers are joined as a pair with a ",", and then separate these pairs with spaces as below.

```
0,78.70536 87.020112,78.70536 87.020112,151.16473680000001 0,151.16473680000001
```

I've tried regexes in sed and ssed (with -r option for perl), but I'm just spinning my wheels.

This is my first question on stackoverflow so apologies if I'm making any n00b errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, join x-y pairs by commas, then join resulting strings by spaces. For example (irrelevant parts are omitted for clarity):

```
.normalizedVertices
| map("\(if has("x") then .x * 320 else 0 end),\(.y * 240)")
| join(" ")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2ORJpA7ByK)</sup>